# Predict time series data from another

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting

**Here is my problem:**

*I have two times series which are highly correlated. One of my time series have one more data point. I would like to predict the other time series missing data.*

For example (**in R**):

```
a = c(126,140,178,223,208,266)
b = c(155,154,220,277,256,334,330)

length(a) < length(b)

cor(a,b[1:6])

names(a) = seq(2000,2005,1)
names(b) = seq(2000,2006,1)
```

**1. My very basic solution is just copy the change of b when I predict a, like this:**

```
ch = (b[7] / b[6]) - 1
a[7] = a[6] + (a[6]*ch)
```

**2. A little bit more complicated version but still basic is this (to predict a from b):**

```
a = c(126,140,178,223,208,266)
b = c(155,154,220,277,256,334,330)
```

**2.1. Give a same "scale" of it (same as plotting a and b to a 1 graph at the same time):**

```
pred = c(NA)

for (i in 1:length(b))
{
pred[i] = ( b[i] / max(b) ) * max(a)
}

2.2 make a custom CI:

mistake = c(NA)

for (i in 1:(length(pred)-1))
{
mistake[i] = (pred[i] / a[i]) -1 
}

sd_mis = sd(mistake)

CI_l = c(NA)
CI_U = c(NA)

for (i in 1:length(pred))
{
CI_l[i] = pred[i] - (pred[i] * sd_mis)
CI_U[i] = pred[i] + (pred[i] * sd_mis)
}

pred = round(pred,0)
CI_l = round(CI_l,0)
CI_U = round(CI_U,0)
```

**2.2 plotting:**

```
plot(pred, type='o', col = "green", xaxt='n', ylim = c(0,max(c(a,pred,CI_l,CI_U))))
lines(a, type='o', col = "black")
lines(CI_l, type='o', col = "red")
lines(CI_U, type='o', col = "red")
axis(side=1, at=seq(1,length(pred),1), labels = seq(2000,2006,1))
```

**3. linear regression**

Linear regression would be a decent solution, but I afraid to use because of a small n.

```
fm <- lm(a ~ b[-7]) 
predict(fm, list(b = 330))
```

**4. Vector autoregression**

I've also tried vector autoregression, but this process needs a same variable length, and also gives me a meaningless result (also because of a small n, I guess)

```
m = matrix(NA,length(a),2)
m[,1] = a
m[,2] = b[-7]

library(vars)

summary(VAR(m))
```

**My questions are:**

1. Is there a more sophisticated way to get the forecasts?*
2. Is my second model mathematically correct?*

Comment: Your real data has 6 observations too?

Comment: Yes! This is one of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plotting your data shows that `a` and `b` appear to be strongly linearly correlated:

```
> dataset <- data.frame(b=b[1:6],a)
> plot(dataset,type="n")
> with(dataset,text(b,a,rownames(dataset)))
```

[image: plot]

However, with no more than six historical observations, anything fancy like VAR or others will likely overfit. In addition, VAR forecasting really only makes sense if you need to forecast *all* components - but here, you already know the 2006 `b` component, you don't need to forecast it.

The simplest thing would be to simply regress `a` on `b`:

```
> model <- lm(a~b,dataset)
> model

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            b  
    17.7859       0.7409
```

Here is the prediction:

```
> predict(model,newdata=data.frame(b=b[7]))

    2006 
262.2801
```

You write that you are afraid of using it because of small `n` - but there really is nothing simpler than this, and with the relationship as obvious as it is here, this is what you should be doing.

---

EDIT: You could also fit an AR model to your `a`, but this will of course only pick up the inherent signal in `a` (`auto.arima(a)` yielded an ARIMA(0,1,0) model with drift), not the relationship with `b`, so it's not using information you have, which is wasteful.

Or you could do a really fancy ARIMAX model for `a` using `b` as an eXternal variable:

```
> library(forecast)
> ar.model <- auto.arima(a,xreg=b[1:6])
> ar.model
Series: a 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean     

Coefficients:
      b[1:6]
      0.8118
s.e.  0.0110

sigma^2 estimated as 42.47:  log likelihood=-19.76
AIC=43.52   AICc=47.52   BIC=43.1
> forecast(ar.model,xreg=b[7])
  Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95  Hi 95
7       267.9071 259.5552 276.2589 255.1341 280.68
```

The result is pretty close to the one from the simple regression.

Anyway, I really wouldn't be using ARIMA(X) with only six observations. Just go with a simple regression.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply! And what about autoregression? I learned that linear regression is not suitable for prediction.

Comment: Why would linear regression not be suitable for prediction? I edited my answer to also include ARIMAX, which I really don't think is justified if you have only six observations.